# null point exception while changing text of fxml label in javafx

Tags: java

public class SerialCommunicationController{

```
    @FXML public Label tempReading;
    @FXML public Label errorReading;

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    private ArduinoInterfaceControl arduinoInterfaceControl;
    private Stage stage;
    private String prop;
    private String inte;
    private String deri;
    private boolean lastCommandSuccessful;
    public static final String LOCAL_SIMULATOR = "Local Simulator";
    private String[] params;
    private ArduinoInterfaceControl arduinoInterface;
    public SerialCommunicationController() {
    }
    public SerialCommunicationController(String cmd){
        setValues(cmd);
    }

    public void setValues(String readings){
        String[] params = readings.split("\\s+");
        // something went wrong, just decode to blank.
        if(params.length < 1) {
            lastCommandSuccessful = false;
        }
        else {
            tempReading.setText(params[0]);
            errorReading.setText(params[1]);
            // successful command received.
            lastCommandSuccessful = Boolean.valueOf(params[1]);
        }
    }

}
```

Hi Guys i am getting `NullPointException` when trying to do `tempReading.setText()` and `errorReading.setText()`. I have defined default values of label text in my fxml file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that both `tempReading` and `errorReading` are null.
Perhaps binding to the FXML is incorrect?

Make sure the `fx:id` in the FXML file matches the names of your Label fields in the Java class.

Comment: Would you be able to also show the FXML file? @ankish